# I dont know why this div is appearing inside another div

Tags: html, css

I have two sections, each takes up the full height and width of the page. One is supposed to be under the other but instead it's appearing inside the other one, even though in the html code they are separate from one another.
The third section div is appearing inside the photo gallery div

```css
.photo-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-collection {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-collection img {
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0;
}

.third-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-gallery">
  <div class="image-collection">
    <img src="http://sahara-experience.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/107620_cb8da068c718b9e6aa7aa0bcbc68d18f_large.jpg" />
    <img src="http://thescienceexplorer.com/sites/thescienceexplorer.com/files/blog/161130141053_1_540x360.jpg" />
    <img src="http://sahara-experience.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/107620_cb8da068c718b9e6aa7aa0bcbc68d18f_large.jpg" />

  </div>
  <div class="image-collection">
    <img src="http://sahara-experience.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/107620_cb8da068c718b9e6aa7aa0bcbc68d18f_large.jpg" />
    <img src="http://thescienceexplorer.com/sites/thescienceexplorer.com/files/blog/161130141053_1_540x360.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.atlasmountainsguide.com/uploads/2/2/5/6/22560216/8975402_orig.jpg" />

  </div>
  <div class="image-collection">
    <img src="http://www.atlasmountainsguide.com/uploads/2/2/5/6/22560216/8975402_orig.jpg" />
    <img src="http://sahara-experience.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/107620_cb8da068c718b9e6aa7aa0bcbc68d18f_large.jpg" />
    <img src="http://thescienceexplorer.com/sites/thescienceexplorer.com/files/blog/161130141053_1_540x360.jpg" />

  </div>

</div>

<div class="third-section">
  <div class="left-side">
    <h3>some title</h3>
    <p>aodubdoaiwodb boabwdo badb aubdabd baodbaob oabd baodbaobd abdibaoib iwbdiab idbaibd oiabdiobao i bdoiab oibadiba ibdaobdaobdbaodadbaidb
    </p>
    <button>LETS GET STARTED</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks fine on JSFiddle .https://jsfiddle.net/w5v4xrjt/
Added border and google's logo to make it clear.

Comment: thanks for trying, maybe its just a big with my browser. im using google chrome.

Comment: I'm using chrome as well, and the sections are all appearing one under the other for me too. Have you looked at the fiddle? If the fiddle is displaying differently than your actual case, then you probably fixed the bug when you created this question.

Comment: i dont quite get what youre saying, how would posting this question fix the bug?